# error executing java class file

Tags: java, linux

I have the following file ~/workspace/A/A.java:

```
package A;
public class A{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

compiling with ecj  don't give me problems,but then I get this error when tring to execute:

```
~/workspace/A $ java A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: A/A)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
~/workspace/A $ java -cp . A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: A/A)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I tried this on Linux Mint 17 with openjdk-7-jre version 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you have the structure **/workspace/A/A.java**
just open the terminal and browse to **workspace** directory then type the following command

For compiling

```
javac A/A.java
```

For executing

```
java A.A
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try compiling your class first and then executing it

```
javac A.java

java A
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you have to compile java program, using below command.

**javac A.java**

Then, run **java A**

Answer (score 0):

First you need to compile using javac A.java

then you also need to specify classpath while running like

java -classpath . A

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if ecj differs from javac, so make sure the A.class file has ended up in same dir as your java file (~/workspace/A/) after compiling and try this:

```
cd ~/workspace
java -cp . A.A
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a JAVA package name in lowercase especially when your classname is same as the package name. You might want to read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html